# c++ using a class object as a class member

Tags: c++, visual-c++, sfml

"cludes.h" is a header file I put all my header files and namespaces in.

**hit_box.h**

```
#include "cludes.h"
class hit_box{
    friend class player;
private:
    /*class members*/
public:
    // without this I get "no default constructor" error. 
    hit_box(); 
    //I think having two constructors will create problems but that's a problem on top of my current problem 

    hit_box(char typ, int t, int x, int y, float Px, float Py,int pw, float spotx, float spoty);
}
```

**player.h**

```
    #pragma once
#include "cludes.h"

class player {
public:
    enum states { falling, hurt, landed, jumping };
    player(float a, float b, int f, sf::Texture t, sf::Texture t2, hit_box pnch);
private:
    //other class members
    hit_box punch;
}
```

**player.cpp**

```
#include "player.h"
#include "cludes.h"
player::player(float a, float b, int f, sf::Texture t, sf::Texture t2, hit_box pnch){
    /*other class members*/
    hit_box punch = pnch;
}
```

I want `hit_box` to be a member I can call on in player class functions.
theses are the error messages I get

> ```
> Error C2061    syntax error: identifier 'hit_box' 
> Error C3646    'punch': unknown override specifier
> Error C4430    missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
> ```

I've tried to inherit the `hit_box` class by

**player.h**

```
#include "cludes.h"
class player {
    hit_box punch;
public:
player(float a, float b, int f, sf::Texture t, sf::Texture t2);
}
```

**player.cpp**

```
#include "player.h"
#include "cludes.h"
player::player(float a, float b, int f, sf::Texture t, sf::Texture t2) : punch('!', 10, 30, 64, -10, -10, 20, 4.44, 4.44){
//other class members
}
```

there's no `hit_box` default constructor this way just the non default constructor.
regardless I still get

> ```
> Error C3646    'punch': unknown override specifier
> Error C4430    missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
> ```

I'm using sfml if that's important info.

Comment: Is this the actual code you're trying to compile? At the very least, you are missing semicolons after each class definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have hit_box defined in hit_box.h, but none of your files that use it `#include <hit_box.h>`. The compiler doesn't know what a `hit_box` is when compiling that code.

Add to your player.h file

```
#include "cludes.h"
#include "hit_box.h"
class player {
```

"'cludes.h" is a header file I put all my header files and namespaces in."

If cludes.h `#includes` your other header files, you have circular dependencies and you need to [forward declare.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c/)

Comment: thanks for the help.                                                                                                                 For anyone dealing with my problem, its best to just inherit the class and not take lazy short cuts like putting all your header files in one file.